# Running jquery in a php while loop

Tags: php, jquery, while-loop

Ok so here it is.

I have a index.php page.  What it does is either make the html page or run a while loop.

It will only run the loop after you fill in some info and press a submit button on the html page.  Now on the html page at the bottom i have it say "__ actions have been completed" with the blank being a variable that has 1 added to it each time the loop is run.

Now what i want to happen is that number to update everytime the loop is run.  I have also been told to us ajax/jquery to do this but i have been unable to figure it out.

So what can i put in the while loop to have the variable update?

```
<?php
$number = $_POST['number'];
if(isset($number)){}
else{
    $number = 0;
}
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $MN = $_POST['MN'];
    $count = $_POST['count'];
    $provider = $_POST['provider'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $m = rand(10e16, 10e20);
        $n = base_convert(¤m, 10, 36);
        $subject = $m;
        $body =  $n;
        $number = $number + 1;
    }
}
echo <<<END
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html> 
  <body>
    <form action="$PHP_SELF" method="post">
    <center> <p>
    <label><b><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>Page</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></b></label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <p>
    <label><strong><u>MN</u></label>
    </p>
    <input name="MN" type="text" value=""/>
    </p>
    <p>
    <p>
    <label><strong><u>Number to Send</u></label>
    </p>
   <input name="count" type="text" value = "1"/>
     <input name = "number" type = "hidden" value = "$number"/>
    </p>
    <p>
    <p>
    <label><strong><u>Provider</u></label>
    </p>
    <select name="provider">
        <option value="">Choose One...</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input name = "Submit" type = "submit" value = "Send"></a>
    </p>
    <p>You have done {$number} actions</p>
    </center>
    </body></html>

    </style>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: normal;
        color: #FF0000;
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    .style7 {color: #FF0000}
END;
?>
```

Comment: show some code, no body like guessing an answer

Answer (score 2):

What you could do, is use a session variable to record the number of times the user has completed the action.

```
if (!$_SESSION["times"]) $_SESSION["times"] = 0;
else $_SESSION["times"]++
```

Then in the HTML, output that variable.

Comment: im not trying to show how many times the user completed a action i am trying to have the user see how many times the loop has run in real time,  I updated my post to clarify this

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do isn't possible (well, not in the way you think).

If I had to do this as an absolute requirement (even though it stinks of poor design) I would do it like so:

Wherever your number is in the original output file, wrap it in a div or span and give it a unique id.

I would then use a session variable for your loop counter.

Finally, I would use jQuery with the timers plugin to fire off at 1 or 2 second intervals.  Within the timer, you should call a .php file in the background that simply returns the value of the session variable.

Here's a bit of code to demonstrate:

(Edited to clarify based on comments below)

Here is a working example:

```
<?php
    // main_page.php

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['loop_count'] = 0;
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Background Updating Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="PATH_TO_YOUR_SCRIPTS/timers.jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'exec_loop.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#status_message').html("Loop started...");
                    }
                });

                 $(document).everyTime(1000, function() {
                     $.ajax({
                         url: 'get_counter.php',
                         success: function(data) {
                             $('#counter_text').html(data);
                         }
                     });
                 });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        The loop has executed <span id='counter_text'>0</span> times.
    </body>
</html>
```

Then in the get_counter.php file, just do something like this:

```
<?php
    // get_counter.php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['loop_count'];
?>
```

Now for the loop file

```
<?php
    // exec_loop.php

    session_start();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 50000000; $i++) {
        $_SESSION['loop_count']++;
    }
?>
```

Save these three files, and you'll get the result you desire.

Comment: so where would i put the 2nd piece of coding(the timer)

Comment: Thinking more about this, you should be doing your loop in a separate file, because php will buffer your output until the loop is done.  So move your loop code to a second php file, and do a similar ajax call from your front end.  Both functions should be in your jQuery $(document).ready() function.

Comment: where would the $(document).ready() function be.  I got all the code down and uploaded and it kinda sorta doesnt work right now.  It will display 0 but when i submit the file it doesnt update the number and when it is done it goes to a white screen,  when i press the back arrow or go back to the page it shows the correct number though.  And how should i work the submit button

Comment: the document ready function goes on your main page within a script tag.  jQuery won't execute the code inside until the document has been rendered by the browser.  You have the proper plugins, right? jQuery & jQuery timers?

Comment: proper plugins                   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.timers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>               with http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.timers-1.2.js.txt being the timer code                                 and is <form action="exec_loop.php" method="post"> the right code for sending the submit button or should i do something different

Comment: No, you don't want a submit to start the loop.  That will take you away from your page and negate the ajax.  Start the loop behind the scenes with the ajax call above.

Comment: I knew there was something wrong there once i looked at it,  so would i just send it to like php self and the above code would do the rest

Comment: Look at my new edits.  It's a complete 3 file example.  1st page is what faces the user.  2nd page is what returns the results to the 1st page via an ajax timer that fires 1 time per second.  3rd page is the actual loop file, which is executed by the 1st page, also via an ajax call, when the page has finished loading.

Comment: well when i run the code that you posted it says "The loop has executed 0 times. " and doesn't change until it says "The loop has executed 50000000 times. " It doesn't show anything in between even if i put a sleep in the loop.   And for the path to the timer if it is in the same directory as the php files would it just be src="timers.jquery.js"

Comment: Well, the loop isn't doing anything.  It's probably finishing in under the 1 second timer resolution.  If memory serves, it takes at least 200ms to do a complete ajax call, so that's the best resolution you'll get.  Of course, your loop probably does something, so it takes longer.

Comment: but even if this is the code <?php
    // exec_loop.php

    session_start();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $_SESSION['loop_count']++;
  sleep(1);
    }
?>
the same thing happens

Comment: Well, you should do some further investigation.  It's possible that the sessions are not updating quick enough.  It's possible that they're missing each other (front and back-end).  It's possible that the code is simply not running in a concurrent fashion to do what you want.  The reality is that you're talking about 3 code files, spread across 2 timing spectrums, with 2 different machines doing the timing, you may just not get the results you need.  It's difficult enough with multiple threads on one machine.  Get some finer grained timing info to see where the problem lies.

Comment: you think if i used a javascript loop and called a php file from it that it could work

Answer (score 0):

i have modified your code so it can use jquery ajax to submit the form 
the response is a json string , we parse it with jquery to get an javascript object 
this your form code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html> 
    <head>
     <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-style: normal;
            line-height: normal;
            color: #FF0000;
            background-color: #000000;
        }
       .style7 {color: #FF0000}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#Submit").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"process.php",
                    type:"get",
                    data:$("form").serialize(),
                    success:function(response){
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
                        var success = obj.success;
                        var actionsNumber = obj.number;
                        $("#result").html('You have done  '+actionsNumber+'  actions');                     
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    </script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <center> <p>
    <label><b><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>Page</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></b></label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <p>
    <label><strong><u>MN</u></label>
    </p>
    <input name="MN" type="text" value=""/>
    </p>
    <p>
    <p>
    <label><strong><u>Number to Send</u></label>
    </p>
   <input name="count" type="text" value = "1"/>
     <input name = "number" type = "hidden" value = "$number"/>
    </p>
    <p>
    <p>
    <label><strong><u>Provider</u></label>
    </p>
    <select name="provider">
        <option value="">Choose One...</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input id="Submit" type = "button" value = "Send">
    </p>
    <p id="result"></p>
    </center>
    </body></html>
```

and the code of process.php :

```
<?php session_start();
// process your form data as you do 
//:::::::::
//
if(!isset($_SESSION['number'])){
      $_SESSION['number'] = 0;
    }
$number =  $_SESSION['number']++;

// output json response 
echo'{"success":"true","number":"'.$number.'"}';
?>
```

we store the number in the session and increment it every action ( call of process.php)
and update the paragraph id="result" with the response.number

hope that help

Comment: How would i make the ajax function call the process.php count umber of times?

Comment: ok, so i have been toying with this code and to get use out of it i need a loop around the ajax stuff, but when i add one whenever i press submit the whole browser gets incredibly laggy,  any way to alleviate this?